# sqlcmd - output to csv | each value in single column

Tags: powershell, csv, output, export-to-csv, sqlcmd

What I do:

```
$data = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "USE DB-Name SELECT DISTINCT name1, name2, name3, name4, name5 FROM Table WHERE Name1 in ('Servername')" -ServerInstance "Name"
  | Format-Table
```

When I `Out-File` this, I've got this in one string/field:

```
"value1","value2","value3","value4","value5"
```

What I need: every value in a separate column in a `.csv` file.

What I've tried:

```
$data | Out-File -Path C:\users\Username\Desktop\List.csv -h-1 -W
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: `Export-CSV` is the direction you should start with.

Comment: You should not use formatters when storing something in a variable; you no longer have usable data after you do that.